# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Rails + Puma + Nginx (Dockerized)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, puma

I'm running a dockerized rails app with puma and nginx, however, I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when trying to access the application from a browser.
I have `config.force_ssl = true` on my application.rb and this is my nginx conf file:

```
upstream kisoul {
  server rails:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /usr/share/nginx/kisoul;

  try_files $uri @kisoul;

  location @kisoul {
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_ignore_headers       Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_set_header           Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass_header          Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass                 http://kisoul;
  }

  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
}
```

I have already tried disabling `force_ssl` from rails and forcing the redirect through nginx, but then I get a problem with Origin header, saying that the origin header (https://localhost) didn't match request.base_url (HTTP://localhost)

I tried many different solutions already described here, but I couldn't find any solution

Comment: Whenever I mess with this stuff and then get that error specifically the first thing I do is make sure to clear out all cookies, or opening it up in a different browser window.  Not sure if it will solve your issue but I would try that first.

Answer (score 0):

The line below, in your NGINX configuration, should fix `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` when `config.force_ssl = true` in your Ruby on Rails application.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Take a look at the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` that I worked recently, rails + puma + nginx + let's encrypt:

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/var/www/mydomain/tmp/puma.sock;
}

server {
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

  root /var/www/mydomain/public;
  access_log /var/www/mydomain/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/mydomain/log/nginx.error.log;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```